# Кракозябры при чтении из MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка, jdbc

При чтении русских слов из базы на jsp-страницу выдаются иероглифы. На сервере MySQL стоит кодировка latin1, при чтениии первым запросом делаю:

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

Все равно не помогает. При выводе из стандартной ком. строки mysql все выводится нормально. Уже и кодировку при создании таблицы менял, все равно не помогает. Как сделать, чтоб нормально считывало русские буквы из базы? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала при заносе в базу поставьте соединение к ней в такую же кодировку. Далее убедитесь, что у вас страница в браузер выдается тоже с этой же кодировкой.

Comment: делал, не помогает(

Comment: а зачем lati1 делаете кодировку а не собственно говоря utf8_general_ci ???

Comment: По умолчанию стояла, но я ее при создании базы менял, не помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите в базе таблицы, какие у них кодировки, у таблицы и отдельно у полей. Встречал уже такие базы, когда таблица в утф8, а отдельное поле в ней почему-то попалось 1251 (не знаю, может кто-то специально делал сначала под себя), но русские буквы из нее так же выводило ненормально, хотя строковой запрос показывал все нормально.

Comment: почему то когда ставлю "set names cp866" , то выводит вопросы. А вот когда ставлю "set names utf8_general_ci" то вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Значит, у вас поля сделаны в этой кодировке. Проверьте. Но вот если в базе поменяете кодировку полей, то все русские просто вылетят и будете заново заполнять ее. (utf8\_general_ci - это кодировка таблиц. UTF8. а general_ci это означает что поле будет регистронезависимым (строчные=прописные - для поиска удобно) а указание для бузы быдет все то же SET NAMES UTF8)

Comment: pначит в браузер выводит не утф8. откройте страницу вывода и посмотрите кодировку через вид - кодировка.
удостоверьтесь что при записи тоже обращение к базе идет через кодировку утф8. ищите везде. найдите соединение с базой когда в ячейки заносятся тексты на русском

Comment: Все уже давно получилось!

Answer (score 0):

как вариант добавить в web.xml фильтр CharsetFilter
Собственно сам фильтр:

```
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {
 private String encoding;

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
  encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
  if (encoding == null)
   encoding = "UTF-8";
 }

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
   FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
  request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
  response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
  next.doFilter(request, response);
 }

public void destroy() {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', t.`TABLE_NAME`, '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') as sqlcode
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` t
WHERE 1
AND t.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'db_name'
ORDER BY 1
```

db_name замените на имя своей базы данных (схемы), а utf8 на нужную вам кодировку.

Comment: Уже ДАВНО все сделано. Просто надо было при внесении из консоли писать <code>SET NAMES cp866</code>